# Question about decreasing AlexaRank

Tags: analytics, alexa

We all know that Alexa ranking is not accurate as it make use of only the visits by the users having the Alexa toolbar installed in the browser.

My question is, I'm regularly tracking the visits of a website using Google Analytics. The traffic remains the same but the Alexa ranking dropped heavily. Can anyone explain this? Can anything be done about this?

I've already done tweaks like installing Alexa toolbar, having customized Alexa toolbar installation option on the website and blogs (which was a success). Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you want a high rank with Alexa in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, just to make my retard boss happy :) Explaining the stuff to him and make him understand it, will take my entire life. Also I dont have a genuine answer when he asks about our competitor's alexa rank which is kinda constant all the time.

Comment: Why do you even care one bit about Alexa rank? It's useless. You're wasting your time chasing nothing.

Comment: @JohnConde.. I know AlexaRank makes no sense, I'm just checking, coz that's the only area that my website lags.

Answer (score 1):

You can include one of [Alexa’s widgets](http://www.alexa.com/siteowners/widgets) on your site. The ones that show your current rank. It will make the page bloated and increase load times (everything you add to it will) but it will track every visitor with Alexa same way you do with Google Analytics.

Comment: Thank you Aeyoun. That's the only thing that I haven't done yet. But will it increase alexa ranking? I'm not sure. Any idea why the alexa is down even when the site is performing well in terms of visitors and SEO?

Comment: Well, @prasad-ebk; your site may not be popular with the Irish. If I remember correctly, they account for a big chunk of the Alexa toolbar users. The rank widget should track users. Read Alexa’s privacy policy to confirm how they use data collected by it.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa ranking is one of the most biased metric in the SEO field. Unlike Google Analytics, Alexa generates its data from the widgets and toolbar installed on your users' computers. If your traffic to your website is mainly from people with no Alexa toolbars installed, Alexa cant detect it, and hence your traffic may show a decrease.

Stop using Alexa and stick to something worthwhile like Google Analytics.